# Android Studio oracle Interworking

Tags: android-studio, ojdbc

The Oracle DB version I'm currently using is 12.2.0.1, so I know that I need to use ojdbc8. However, the error below appears.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.mes, PID: 32083
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/DriverAction;
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
                                                                                                        at com.example.mes.ConnectDB.connectionDB(ConnectDB.java:32)
                                                                                                        at com.example.mes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8926)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8904)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4147)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4323)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2686)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8873)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.sql.DriverAction" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~xbQoZkEQhgx-AuMvkldFHQ==/com.example.mes-xhA0F2bedJEvsN7UKWEVAg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~xbQoZkEQhgx-AuMvkldFHQ==/com.example.mes-xhA0F2bedJEvsN7UKWEVAg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) 
                                                                                                        at com.example.mes.ConnectDB.connectionDB(ConnectDB.java:32) 
                                                                                                        at com.example.mes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8926) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8904) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4147) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4323) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2686) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8873) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608) 
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
```

Version 8 of ojdbc was saved in the libs folder,
I included the code in build.gradle(:app) as below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('D:\\Android Tutorial\\mes\\app\\libs\\ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar') //추가
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

file > settins > build, exectuion, deployment > build tools > gradle
gradle jdk
1.8 oracle openjdk 1.8.0_381,
11 Oracle OpenJDK version

I tried changing it to the jdk versions above.